# How do i pass .JSON file from LWC to apex method

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, json

I have a requirement to get the value of all fields with name "Settlement Date" from .JSON  file. The JSON file looks like this

```
{
    "GenerationTime": "20200119170533",
    "ResponseCode": "MSK",
    "ValidationExceptions": [{
            "SettlementDate": "20200113",
            "MSL": "_A",
            "MSN": {
                "ImportMSID": "MSID",
                "ExportMSID": null
            },
            "MRA": {
                "SettlementPeriod": 34,
                "DeliveredVolume": 23,
                "ExceptionReason": "The import volume doesnot match with the actual allocation"
            }
        }, {
            "SettlementDate": "20200114",
            "MSL": "_B",
            "MSN": {
                "ImportMSID": "MSID",
                "ExportMSID": null
            },
            "MRA": {
                "SettlementPeriod": 45,
                "DeliveredVolume": 21,
                "ExceptionReason": "The import volume doesnot match with the actual allocation"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Can .JSON file directly be sent as JSON from lwc to apex method which can then be deserialized . Or the JSON file first needs to be encoded in base64 or application/x-www-form-urlencoded format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can send JSON directly to an Apex method:

```
myApexMethod({jsonString: source})
.then(result=>...)
.catch(error=>...);
```

And in Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled public static void myApexMethod(String jsonString) {
  Map<String, Object> parsedData = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);
  ...
```

Or, you can try using json2apex to form a wrapper, and pass in the value directly as a regular object.

```
myApexMethod({data: source})
.then(result=>...)
.catch(error=>...);
```

...

```
@AuraEnabled public static void myApexMethod(ParamWrapper data) {
  ...
```

Comment: This should read `myApexMethod({jsonString: JSON.stringify(source)})` - but the real question is how can we just pass actual JSON objects to Apex without constantly converting stuff to strings and back.